# What makes R unique?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, real-numbers

I am currently taking Introductory Analysis and my professor asked us to consider "why is R unique?"

He said some of the things to possibly take into account are it's a field, it is ordered, it has the Least Upper Bound Property and the fact that Q ⊆ R.

I am not sure what he is expecting us to learn and Google and Stack Exchange searches are not returning much.

What is this uniqueness?

Comment: He's is not expecting you to do web searches, he is expecting you to think.

Comment: $\Bbb Q\subseteq \Bbb R$ becomes redundant as soon as you require $\Bbb R$ to be an ordered field.

Comment: In spite of its title "Topology" by Dieudonne is a book on Analysis . It has a clear and concise account of why there is, up to isomorphism, just one ordered field with the LUB property,  Which one of them you want to call $\Bbb R$ is therefore moot,

Answer (score 1):

Write down what you think are the key axioms that define $\mathbb{R}$. Then think about the following:

1) Are the axioms you've written down sufficient to pin down $\mathbb{R}$ uniquely? Are you sure $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{C}$ do not also satisfy your axioms? What about integers mod $p$? $2 \times 2$ matrices with real coefficients? Other, more exotic number systems?

2) What about the set of matrices $\left[\begin{array}{cc}a & 0\\ 0 & a\end{array}\right]$, $a\in\mathbb{R}$? Does it satisfy your axioms? Does this mean you haven't sufficiently pinned down the real numbers? Why or why not?

3) Can you *prove* your answers to part 1 and 2?

4) Are your axioms all necessary? Do some imply the others? How do you *know*?

Answer (score 1):

The reals are the unique complete totally ordered field, up to isomorphism. Let’s unpack this.

Field: You have 0, 1, commutative, associative, and total multiplication and addition, total subtraction, and (aside from 0 on the right) total division.

Up to isomorphism: You can label the elements however you like. Aside from the distinguished elements 0 and 1 you could call 1+1 “two” or “dos” or “II” and it wouldn’t change anything.

Ordered: There is an order $\le$, and it is transitive: if $a \le b$ and $b \le c$, then $a \le c$.

Totally: The order is total, that is, for any a and b, at least one of $a \le b$ and $b \le a$ are true.

Complete: Informally, no in-between points are missing. If you can construct a sequence which gets closer and closer together (a Cauchy sequence), it has a limit.

Unique: Subject to the isomorphism caveat, there’s only one way to do this.

In summary: Once you pick 0 and 1 as starting points, then construct elements by field operations or by Cauchy sequences, you inevitably end up with the real numbers — the only choices you have are how to label the elements.

Comment: You have 22k reputation. You should, in my opinion, know better than to write <= by now.

Comment: @Arthur Sorry, typing on my phone, I’ll tidy when I get to my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Up to isomorphism, $\mathbb R$ is the only [Dedekind-complete ordered field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Axiomatic_approach).